# Clear user search input for search="text" using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I would like add a clear input text feature to the existing search functionality. When user click the cross animation it should clear the input text instead of moving the arrows away. I have added display:none at last not valid, but not working as expected. Can someone please assist on how to implement this functionality ?.

```css
.search-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  float:right;
}

.search-box input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
  outline: none;
}

.search-box input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 280px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}

.search-box input[type="text"]:focus + span::before {
  height: 14px;
  margin: -22px 0 0 -15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.5s;
}

.search-box input[type="text"]:focus + span::after {
  visibility: visible;
  margin: -22px 0 0 -15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.7s;
}

.search-box span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.search-box span::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: -4px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.2s;
}

.search-box span::after {
  content: '';
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: -36px 0 0 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}



.search-box:not(:valid) ~ span {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<form name="search">
  <label class="search-box">
    <input type="text" />
    <span></span>
  </label> 
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0wansxza/

Comment: Would you consider `type="search"` - or adding `for="search"` to the label for accessibility?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it using jQuery with that `$('#element').val('');`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('.search-box input[type="text"]').focusout(function() {
  jQuery(this).val('');
 })
});
```

```css
.search-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  float:right;
}

.search-box input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
  outline: none;
}

.search-box input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 280px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}

.search-box input[type="text"]:focus + span::before {
  height: 14px;
  margin: -22px 0 0 -15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.5s;
}

.search-box input[type="text"]:focus + span::after {
  visibility: visible;
  margin: -22px 0 0 -15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.7s;
}

.search-box span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.search-box span::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: -4px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.2s;
}

.search-box span::after {
  content: '';
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: -36px 0 0 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}



.search-box:not(:valid) ~ span {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="search">
  <label class="search-box">
    <input type="text" />
    <span></span>
  </label> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Just CSS.  I had to modify your markup a little. To clear the input field i had to add a button that resets the form when clicked. See my code and comments below. Hope it helps

```css
.search-box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  float:right;
}

.search-box input[type="text"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  z-index: 11;/**Changed This**/
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0.5s;
  outline: none;
}
/**Updated the below codes**/
.search-box input[type="text"]:focus,
.search-box .btn:focus + input{
  width: 280px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out 0s;
}
/**Updated the below codes**/
.search-box input[type="text"]:focus + span::before,
.search-box .btn:focus + input[type="text"] + span::before{
  height: 14px;
  margin: -22px 0 0 -15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.5s;
}
/**Updated the below codes**/
.search-box input[type="text"]:focus + span::after,
.search-box .btn:focus + input[type="text"] + span::after{
  visibility: visible;
  margin: -22px 0 0 -15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.7s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.7s;
}

.search-box span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.search-box span::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: -4px 0 0 0;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0.2s;
}

.search-box span::after {
  content: '';
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 14px;
  margin: -36px 0 0 5px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}
/**
.search-box:not(:valid) ~ span {
 display: none;
}**/

/**Added the below codes**/
.search-box .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    width: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 11;
}
```

```html
<form name="search">
  <label class="search-box">
  <!--Added the button to clear the field  on click-->
    <button class="btn" type="reset"></button>
    <input type="text" />
    <span></span>
  </label> 
</form>
```